# Enabling large-file uploads for authorized users only in ASP.NET with IIS?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, file-upload, large-files

I have an ASP.NET application, and need to add the ability to upload large files. However, I need to do it securely, such that a user won't be able to overwhelm the server with a large request. Basically, my requirements are:

1. **Unauthorized user cannot upload files** (cannot cause excessive disk space or memory to be consumed on the server). As the request is streaming in, as soon as it exceeds some small threshold (e.g. 4MB), it should immediately be rejected (or else allowed to continue but discarded on the server *without* being buffered in memory or on disk, including in any temporary files/folders)
2. **Authorized user can upload very large files** (e.g. 100MB, in any case much larger than the 4MB default ASP.NET request size limit)
3. (OPTIONAL) Authorized user can't consume arbitrary amount of disk space (say, no more than 250MB)

These seem like pretty basic security requirements - but looking at ASP.NET/IIS docs, I'm having a surprisingly hard time understanding how to make this happen, or indeed whether it's even possible out-of-the-box. There are `maxAllowedContentLength` and `maxRequestLength` settings, but they are not affected by the authorization status of the user. If I understand correctly, if you set a larger value for these settings for an auth-required section of the site, a large upload would still be able to proceed (and will be buffered to disk) before the auth check happens.

How can I meet the requirements above?